# Numpy - summing up a list of vectors

Tags: python, list, numpy, vector

I am trying to sum a list of NumPy vectors in a list. (In this example it's a list of 2 items, but in my case the list can be of any size.) How to sum them into a new vector?

```
a = np.array([100, 100])
b = np.array([200, 200])
my_list = [a, b]

ab = np.add(my_list)
```

`np.add(a, b)` works, but it's not a list. I have already tried `np.add(*my_list)` and `np.add(np.array(my_list))` as well as `np.add(np.array([my_list]))`, but without any success. What would be the correct way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Solution 1 `np.add.reduce()`

You can use the `reduce` attribute of `np.add`:

```
a = np.array([100, 100])
b = np.array([200, 200])
c = np.array([1000, 2000])
L = [a, b, c]
np.add.reduce(L)
```

results in:

```
array([1300, 2300])
```

All universal function that take two in-arguments have a `reduce` attribute, that applies this function like `reduce`, i.e.:

```
np.add.reduce(L)
```

becomes:

```
np.add(np.add(L[0], L[1]), L[2])
```

Add more parenthesis and appropriate `np.add` calls if the list `L` gets larger.

From the docs:

> Docstring:
>
> ```
>   reduce(a, axis=0, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False)
> ```
>
> Reduces `a`'s dimension by one, by applying ufunc along one axis.

### Solution 2 `np.sum()`

Alternatively, you can use `np.sum` along the first axis:

```
>>> np.sum(L, axis=0)
array([1300, 2300
```

### Performance

The performance of both seems to be the same.

For small arrays:

```
a = np.array([100, 100])
b = np.array([200, 200])
c = np.array([1000, 2000])
L = [a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c]
```

`reduce` is a little bit faster:

```
%timeit np.sum(L, axis=0)

10000 loops, best of 3: 20.7 µs per loop

%timeit np.add.reduce(L)
100000 loops, best of 3: 15.7 µs per loop
```

For large arrays:

```
size = int(1e6)
a = np.random.random(size)
b = np.random.random(size)
c = np.random.random(size)
L = [a, b, c, a, b, c, a, b, c]
```

There is no difference:

```
%timeit np.sum(L, axis=0)
10 loops, best of 3: 41.5 ms per loop

%timeit np.add.reduce(L)
10 loops, best of 3: 41.9 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you mean?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([100, 100])
b = np.array([200, 200])
my_list = [a, b]

# add them up "vertically"

print np.vstack(my_list).sum(axis=0)

print np.vstack(tuple(my_list)).sum(axis=0)  # I thought it had to be a tuple but apparently not!


[300 300]
[300 300]
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but to me, `reduce` seems to be simpler.

Comment: I've never used that before, learned something new! I wonder what the differences are....

Comment: According the documentation, it is the same: "applying along one axis". http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduce.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use `np.hstack` or `np.concatenate`:

```
l = [a, b]

In [560]: np.hstack(l)
Out[560]: array([100, 100, 200, 200])

In [561]: np.concatenate(l)
Out[561]: array([100, 100, 200, 200])
```

Comment: This is not summing, but concatenating.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an ideal candidate for reduce

```
>>> a = np.array([100, 100])
>>> b = np.array([200, 200])
>>> c = np.array([300, 300])
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: np.add(x,y), [a,b,c])
array([600, 600])
```